# How to get multiple column data from two tables in one view

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get data from two tables(brands and raw_materials), connected by a foreign key (brand_id). A brand can have multiple raw materials. I want it all displaying under its respective brand on one page. Instead, I get the results displayed separately.

Using Laravel 5.7 and Eloquent.

```
My Tables
[brands]
id    name
----------
1   Apple 
2   Colgate
3   LintX

[raw_materials]
id    name        brand_id      quantity
-----------------------------------------
1    50g pouch        1        200
2    10g laminate     3        320
3    75mm oil         1        500
4    Mint Rubber      3        400
5    Fire pouch       2        550
6    400 String       1        500
7    90g pouch        2        200
```

## PageController

```
$brandData = DB::table('brands')
            ->join('raw_materials','raw_materials.brand_id','brands.id')
            ->select('brands.id as brand_id','brands.name as brand_name','raw_materials.name as raw_material','raw_materials.quantity')
            ->orderBy('brands.id')
            ->get();<br>
return view('rawmaterials.index', [
            'brandData'=>$brandData,
        ]);
```

## View

```
@foreach ($brandData as $brand)
<p>Brand Name: {{$brand->brand_name}}</p>
<p>{{$brand->raw_material}} | Quantity: {{$brand->quantity}}</p>
<br>
@endforeach
```

Expected Results:
Brand Name: Apple
50g pouch | Quantity: 200
75mm oil | Quantity: 500
400 String | Quantity: 500
Brand Name: Colgate
Fire pouch | Quantity: 550
75mm oil | Quantity: 500
400 String | Quantity: 500

`next brand ..`
Actual Result:
Brand Name: Apple
50g pouch | Quantity: 200
Brand Name: Apple
75mm oil | Quantity: 500
Brand Name: Apple
400 String | Quantity: 500
Brand Name: Colgate
Fire Pouch | Quantity: 550
`And so on..`

Comment: I strongly suggest you read the docs about Eloquent relationships. That raw SQL join is NOT the way to do this! https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I agree with BlueC. Defining the relation in the model and using eloquent to retrieve the brand data and related materials data will simplify things to you

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
$brandData = \DB::table('brands')->orderBy("brands.id")->get();

foreach ($brandData as $brand) {
    $brand->raw_materials = \DB::table("raw_materials")->where("brand_id", $brand->id)->get();
}

return view('rawmaterials.index', [
            'brandData'=>$brandData
        ]);
```

Then in your view you'll use nested like this ...

```
@foreach ($brandData as $brand)
<p>Brand Name: {{$brand->name}}</p>
@foreach($brand->raw_materials as $raw)
<p>{{$raw->name}} | Quantity: {{$raw->quantity}}</p>
@endforeach
<br>
@endforeach
```

That should get the job done.

On the other hand if you would like to use Eloquent rather you have to set the relationships in both Brand model and RawMaterial model as follows, assuming Brand and RawMaterial models are directly in the app folder

```
class Brand extends Model
{
    public function raw_materials()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\RawMaterial');
    }
}

class RawMaterial extends Model
{
    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Brand');
    }
}
```

Then in your controller you simply do this ...

```
$brandData = \App\Brand::with("raw_materials")->orderBy("id")->get();
```

No need to change the blade syntax in your .blade file as the same foreach loop applies

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks 

Comment: The first part of this answer is a very, very poor solution. It is simply not the Laravel or Eloquent way of doing things, so why bother using Laravel/Eloquent if you're not actually going to use it the way it is intended? Secondly, it suffers from the N+1 problem. The second part, defining the relationships on the models is more like it.

Comment: BlueC I agree with you. I made changes to the code and used  eloquent instead as suggested by @Mcleash. And it works as well. Thanks 

Answer (score 0):

You can create a relationship first:

```
function raw_materials() {
     return $this->hasMany(RawMaterial.class);
}
```

In your controller, use the with() function like so:

```
$brandData = Brand::with('raw_materials')->all();
return view('rawmaterials.index', [
    'brandData'=>$brandData
]);
```

Then in your view, you can get the raw_materials table data:

```
@foreach($branData as $brand)
   <h3>{{ $brand->name }}</h3>
   @foreach($brand->raw_materials as $raw_material)
       <div>{{ $raw_material->name }}</div>
       <div>{{ $raw_material->quantity }}</div>
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Please respect to the contribution of other people if you are posting / modifying the answer from other people's idea. It's better to give reference if you do that.